# Custom PHP MySQL database queries function - Suggestions for improvement or additions

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

For my website needs I made a custom procedural MySQL function in PHP which can INSERT, UPDATE, SELECT or DELETE data from database. I would like a review and any suggestions for improvement or addition of new features.

```
function mysqli_database_query($sql, $values, $param = NULL, $result_param = NULL) {
    require "dbconn.script.php";
    // String to array conversion
    if (!is_array($values)) {
        $values_array = array($values);
    } else {
        $values_array = $values;
    }
    // Number of values checker and string of parameter types creation
    $number_of_values = count($values_array);
    if ($number_of_values > 1) {
        $param_types = implode("", array_map(function($val) { return gettype($val)[0]; }, $values_array));
    } else {
        $param_types = gettype($values_array[0])[0];
    }
    // SQL query execution
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
    mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, $param_types, ...$values_array);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    // SQL query results management
    if (preg_match("/^SELECT.*/", $sql)) {
        $results = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
        # RETURN ASSOCIATIVE AND NUMERIC ARRAY COMBINED EVEN IF RESULT PARAMETER IS INVALID
        if ($result_param === NULL || $result_param !== "assoc" || $result_param !== "num" || $result_param !== "row") {
            return mysqli_fetch_array($results, MYSQLI_BOTH);
        # RETURN ASSOCIATIVE ARRAY
        } else if ($result_param === "assoc") {
            return mysqli_fetch_array($results, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        # RETURN NUMERIC ARRAY
        } else if ($result_param === "num") {
            return mysqli_fetch_array($results, MYSQLI_NUM);
        # RETURN ONE ROW
        } else if ($result_param === "row") {
            if ($param === NULL || $param !== "id") {
                return mysqli_fetch_row($results);
            }
            # RETURN ONE ROW ID
            if ($param === "id") {
                $result = mysqli_fetch_row($results);
                return $result["id"];
            }  
        }
    }
    if (preg_match("/^INSERT.*/", $sql)) {
        # RETURN LAST INSERTED ID
        if ($param === "insert_id") {
            return mysqli_insert_id($conn);
        # RETURN NUMBER OF AFFECTED ROWS
        } else if ($param === "affected_rows") {
            return mysqli_affected_rows($conn);
        } else {
            return false;
        } 
    }
    if (preg_match("/^UPDATE.*/", $sql)) {
        # RETURN NUMBER OF AFFECTED ROWS
        if ($param === "affected_rows") {
            return mysqli_affected_rows($conn);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    if (preg_match("/^DELETE.*/", $sql)) {
        # RETURN NUMBER OF AFFECTED ROWS
        if ($param === "affected_rows") {
            return mysqli_affected_rows($conn);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: In your place I would add some usage examples, to demonstrate how this function is going to be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This monster of a function is hard to use and hard to maintain. Besides, it is bloated with duplicated and/or unnecessary code. Last but not least, the way `require "dbconn.script.php";` is called will make your code run slower and make some features (such as transactions) unavailable.

#### Too many connections

Your current code is connecting to the database every time it runs a query. You shouldn't do that. Always connect strictly  **once** and then pass a connection variable as a function parameter.

#### Useless regexp

You already control the return type buy means of $param variable. No need to check the query type manually. It is useless *and* error prone. What if your query is `CALL`? `SET`? `REPLACE`?

#### Passing values as array is not that hard.

With your function you have a choice, whether to pass $values as array or not. It makes the code hard to read. At the same time adding two square brackets to your $values is not a big deal. So just just make $values an array mandatory.

#### Too much tasks for a function

The first question I must ask, *why only a single function* to perform so many tasks? All right, I can make it you are not familiar with OOP and don't want to use a class (which would be the best solution of course). But why not to make a set of functions, each serving for its own purpose? Why following that horrible practice of procedural mysqli when you have to write a helluvalot of words every time you calling a simple function (`mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt)` vs. `$stmt->get_result()`)?

Here is your intended function call

```
$rows = mysqli_database_query($sql, $id, "affected_rows");
```

compare it with with a code which is shorter but more meaningful and readable at the same time:

```
$rows = mysqli_delete($sql, [$id]);
```

A function name should be meaningful and tell you what does this function do. It should be a function name, not a parameter.

In your place I would create a set of functions. Say, a basic one that just performs a query

```
function mysqli_database_query($conn, $sql, $values, $return_result = true)
{
    $types = $types ?: str_repeat("s", count($params));
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param($types, ...$params);
    $stmt->execute();
    return ($return_result) ? $stmt->get_result() : $stmt;
}
```

and then add some helper functions for various tasks

```
function mysqli_delete($conn, $sql, $values)
{
    $stmt = mysqli_database_query($conn, $sql, $values, false);
    $return $stmt->affected_rows();
}
function mysqli_assoc($conn, $sql, $values)
{
    $result = mysqli_database_query($conn, $sql, $values);
    $return $result->fetch_assoc();
}
function mysqli_all($conn, $sql, $values)
{
    $result = mysqli_database_query($conn, $sql, $values);
    $return $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
}
```

you can use the following  function instead of that awkward $param = "id" of yours, for any column, not only id. Just select the desired column, i.e. `SELECT user_id FROM table ...`:

```
function mysqli_cell($conn, $sql, $values)
{
    $result = mysqli_database_query($conn, $sql, $values);
    $row = $return $result->fetch_row();
    return ($row) ? $row[0] : false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed review of my code. I want to tell you that I am just a beginner in programming, so I still stick to the procedural PHP. I know a little about OOP. I have a few questions more:
- I didn't quite understand what did you mean by passing values as array mandatory. If I have an array of values and I want to add them to my function with ``[]`` as you suggested, it would convert it to a multidimensional array that will not work in my case (I think).
- I cannot grasp this: ``return ($return_result) $stmt->get_result() : $stmt;``. Can you explain it to me?

Comment: And one more thing. How do you call a custom function within another custom function if they are defined within same page? I only succeeded in this by having separate files and the I include file with function1 in file with function2 which uses function1.

Comment: Thank you for the good questions. In your code you have a function that converts $values to array if it is not, `if (!is_array($values))`. What I suggest is to always send $values as array and thus remove this code. A $return_result code is a ternary operator you can Google it up. Based in this variable's value it tells a function to return either a statement or a result

Comment: Ok, I think I understand now. Can you explain me why did you decided to use this code ``$types = $types ?: str_repeat("s", count($params));`` for generating variable types, instead of my version - ``$param_types = implode("", array_map(function($val) { return gettype($val)[0]; }, $values_array));``?

Comment: MySQL will gladly accept all types as strings, no need for anything else. Besides, such a code like yours could lead to problems. I wrote about it several times, let me find it

Comment: Also, as I understand this code ``$types = $types ?: str_repeat("s", count($params));`` it evaluated if $types are set. If not, it will generate it from the number of array members? Am I correct? And if I am, where should those be set previously? As one of the function arguments?

Comment: I am terribly sorry, it's a bad copy paste from my [function](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli/simple) that accepts an optional types variable

Comment: Ok, everything is clear now. Thank you very much for your help.